# Can't change default user language in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Like I wrote in the title I cannot change the user default language.I open Security -> logins -> RMB on particular user -> property. And when I change the default language to different and save it by clicking OK, then I open it again and there is still Arabic language. The same happens with any other user on the server. 
[image]

The odd thing is the fact that default server language is set to English.
[image]

Below I pasted the server specification:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to change the default user language? Even If I create a new user and set the language to any different language then Arabic(straight away) it always changes to Arabic automatically.

Comment: Won't lie, seems *really* odd that the **`LOGIN`**'s (not `USER`'s) default language is arabic, when the Server's is English (United States) and it's collation is `Polish_CI_AS`. That's 3 very different countries there.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it with T-SQL instead:

```
ALTER LOGIN [Your Login] SET DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH;
```

Then check the actual value in the system table:

```
SELECT sp.default_language_name
FROM sys.server_principals sp
WHERE sp.[name] = N'Your Login';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Before I run ALTER LOGIN, I checked sp.default_language_name and got polish as the result. Then I run ALTER LOGIN [Your Login] SET DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH, and the sp.default_language_name for the user got changed to English. But unfortunately, the user default language hasn't changed at all, still Arabic.  Like it was before.

Comment: If the value of `default_language_name` is `English` then the `LOGIN`'s default language is definately that, @GrzegorzSpytek . I ***assume*** you have disconnected and reconnected. The default language for an existing connection won't change when you `ALTER` a `LOGIN`.